# Why NodeJS put request doesn't update the property, it only returns the id of the object

Tags: node.js, express, joi

There is a slight problem with updating the object via put request in my code. When i send put request with postman, request returns only the id of the genre object. Genre object has an id and a name properties.

```
app.put('/vidly/genres/:id', (req, res) => {

    const genre = genres.find(g => g.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!genre) return res.status(404).send('The genre was not found.');
  
    const result = validateGenre(req.body.name); 
    if (result.error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    genre.name = req.body.name;
    res.send(genre);
  });

  function validateGenre(genre) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
      name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    });
    
    return schema.validate(genre);
    };
```

I am struggling to find a proper solution. Any help would be useful. If somebody could explain what am i doing wrong so i can have better understanding of this problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The example is validating if `req.body.name` has an additional `.name` property.  The schema also doesn't require the base object, so in this case when `req.body.name` is not defined, the validation passed without even checking for properties.

The schema should make the object itself required.

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
}).required()
```

Then the body can be validated

```
const result = validateGenre(req.body)
if (result.error) {
  return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
}
```

Or possibly the constructed `genre`

```
genre.name = req.body.name
const result = validateGenre(genre)
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your willingness to help out. Though now i receive an ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: The reference to `error` should be `result.error`